# Golang Template Variable Not Rendering

Tags: html, go, templates

Hopefully this is a very simple question for y'all. I'm pretty new to Golang. I've already asked ChatGPT for help and we couldn't figure it out.

I have an HTML page that I'd like to render using a base and partials that get inserted into the base. For some reason I can't get variables to render. Here's my template code:

```
{{define "BASE"}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My site</title>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/image/favicon.png" sizes="96x96"/>

    {{block "STYLES" .}}{{end}}
    {{block "SCRIPTS" .}}{{end}}
</head>
<body>
    {{block "CONTENT" .}}{{end}}
</body>
</html>
{{end}}

{{define "CONTENT"}}
Title: {{.title}}
{{end}}

{{template "BASE"}}
```

Here's my Go code:

```
import "html/template"
import "os"

func main () {
    temp := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("www/html/test.tpl"))
    temp.Execute(os.Stdout, map[string]string{"title":"MYTITLE"})
}
```

Here's my output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My site</title>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/image/favicon.png" sizes="96x96"/>

    
    
</head>
<body>
    
Title: 

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the .title variable does not render. Would anyone be able to tell me why?

I also think it's kind of weird I have to put `{{template "BASE"}}` in the template itself. I'm using Gin and it doesn't seem to render anything unless I do that.

If I use `temp.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "BASE", ...)` with the `{{template "BASE"}}` removed it works. Am I using Gin wrong?

Comment: Your template seems to be missing a `{{define "template_name"}}` action at the top, right? And if not, then you have an "orphaned" `{{end}}` action right after `</html>`.

Comment: *"I also think it's kind of weird I have to put {{template "BASE"}} in the template itself."* -- This is only necessary if you explicitly define the template with the `{{ define "template_name"}}` action. If the file has content at the top level (outside of any define action), then that content will be rendered without you having to provide the `{{template ...}}` action.

Comment: Oh that's a good point. Maybe I should just remove the base definition.

Comment: Yep that fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: And I suspect your `.title` in the original version didn't work because you forgot to pass the dot to base, i.e. you have `{{template "BASE"}}` instead of `{{template "BASE" .}}`.